# Counting the results of different rows in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to count the entries in rows in a MySQL table:

Example data:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| facebook_id | linkedin_id | twitter_id | vk_id |
+------------------------------------------------+
  1234143134    0             13413993     13499
  0             0             0            0
  12313431334   0             13413243     0
  12341431340   13419194319   13419943     13413
  0             0             0            0
+------------------------------------------------+
```

The aim is to display how many of each _id has an entry.
In the above example, facebook has 3, LinkedIn has 1 and twitter has 3 and vk has 2.

Here is my attempt at counting them:

```
COUNT(`facebook_id`) AS `facebook`,
COUNT(`linkedin_id`) AS `linkedin`,
COUNT(`twitter_id`) AS `twitter`,
COUNT(`vk_id`) AS `vkontakte`
FROM `user`
```

How can this be fixed? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUM()` like this:

```
select 
  sum(facebook_id <> 0) facebook, 
  sum(linkedin_id <> 0) linkedin,
  sum(twitter_id <> 0) twitter,
  sum(vk_id <> 0) vk
from `user`
```

Each of the boolean expressions like:

```
facebook_id <> 0
```

evaluates to 1 or 0.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eWjS1WLpPJbBfjgYFUytVb/1).
Results:

```
| facebook | linkedin | twitter | vk  |
| -------- | -------- | ------- | --- |
| 3        | 1        | 3       | 2   |
```

Comment: we could also write `SUM(CASE WHEN facebook_id <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` to get an equivalent result +10

Comment: Your code is the standard way for this requirement, but since MySql offers this feature I use it.